# What are some reasons why I periodically get a JDBC MySQL communications link failure in my program?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-ec2

I have an instance of MySQL deployed on an Amazon EC2 server, along with a Java .Jar file that connects to the local database to archive metadata retrieved from an API. I have the Java file automatically executed 4 times daily via a Linux Crontab Task.

My code will always run and connect to MySQL fine initially but then it will experience a JDBC Communications link failure around a minute into its execution (the timeframe that this occurs can vary, however). This is the following error message that is displayed to the terminal:

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 4,278 milliseconds ago.

Prior to the above error message being displayed, my program appears to freeze. The freezing of my program is evident because it will stop outputting: "A metadata point was archived". I have my program output that everytime a metadata point from an API is archived accordingly into my database's tables.

I've attempted many solutions in order to fix this problem and I'm at a complete loss as to what is causing it. I've added multiple parameters to my url string:
jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYDBNAME?serverTimezone=EST5EDT&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&maxReconnects=10&failOverReadOnly=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useUnicode=true&tcpKeepAlive=true&interactiveClient=true
The autoReconnect parameter will sometimes allow my program to reconnect to the database after the communications link failure and to re-execute, but sometimes it won't help at all.

I've ensured that my program is not closing the JDBC connection until after the program's completion.
I've ensured that all of my preparedstatements and resultsets are being closed within a finally block after executing or retrieving the values from them.

I've ensured that the version of MySQL connector java driver.jar that my program is using matches the version of the installed MySQL database.

I've tried increasing MySQL's built-in timeout variables.

The following is the method that i use to initialize the connection global variable that is used exclusively by methods within this class for queries.

```
private void setUpConnectionToDatabase() { 
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                url, username, password); // connects to server using url, username, password.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        connection=null;
    }
}
```

The following is one of my methods that queries the database, let me know if you see any errors. Other methods within the class essentially follow the same format. Notice that the connection variable itself *does not* get closed within the method.

```
public Coordinates getCoordsFromArchivedLocationData(String bioLocation) {
    Coordinates coords= new Coordinates();
    double lat=0;
    double longit=0;
    String queryStatement= "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM archived_location_data WHERE LocationName=?;";
    PreparedStatement query=null;
    ResultSet result=null;

    try {
        query = connection.prepareStatement(queryStatement);
        query.setString(1, bioLocation);
        result = query.executeQuery();
        if(result.next()) {
            lat= result.getDouble(1);
            longit= result.getDouble(2);
        }
        coords.setLatitude(lat);
        coords.setLongitude(longit);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return coords;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(query != null) {
            query.close();
            }
            if(result != null) {
            result.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return coords;


}
```

Comment: _"I've ensured that my program is not closing the JDBC connection until after the program's completion."_ Instead, try using a connection pool, and get a connection from that pool, and close it as soon as a unit of work is done (closing returns it to the pool). Having very long running connections could be automatically killed by the server, and you can configure the connection pool to replace aging connections.